# в django3 ./manage.py migrate не работает zsh: no such file or directory: ./manage.py

Tags: django-rest-framework

в django3 не работает команда  ./manage.py migrate в терминале Pycharm на MacOs. zsh: no such file or directory: ./manage.py

Comment: Точка в `./manage.py` означает, что файл запускается из текущей директории. Если в текущей директории нет этого файла - то естественно он не запустится. В терминале нужно сначала с помощью команды `cd` перейти в нужную директорию, потом выполнить `./manage.py`, или указать полный путь до этого файла.

Comment: Благодарочка! Точно!

Comment: ошибка была в том что в команде надо было поставить 3 после python! вот и всё! python3 manage.py migrate